# Using variables in Gruntfile.js

Tags: variables, gruntjs

I have a `Gruntfile.js`, where *I have a string I's repeating many times*. So I decided to proceed with a variable, hence I introduced `var file_path`.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    var today = new Date();
    var year  = today.getFullYear();

    var file_path = 'here/there/';

    grunt.initConfig({

        jshint: {
            all: [
                '<%= file_path %>/assets/js/app.js',
                '<%= file_path %>/admin/assets/js/admin.js',
            ]
        },

    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

};
```

But it's not working. Throwing the following error:

> `Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task`
>   `Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (file_path is not defined). Use --force to continue.`

When I changed `<%= file_path %>` to `<%= this.file_path %>`, the process runs but the paths are not resolved.

> `Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task`
>   `>> 0 files linted. Please check your ignored files.`

With other registered tasks it's confirmed that, `No source files were found.`.

BTW I incorporated `year` in another task that is working fine. Attached a screenshot:

[image: Variable Year in Gruntfile]

So, I tried the same syntax in `jshint` task, like below:

```
all: [
    file_path +  'assets/js/app.js',
    file_path +  'admin/assets/js/admin.js',
]
```

It's producing the same result of not linting any file at all.

However I tried the following console.log, *outside* of `grunt.initConfig()`:

```
grunt.log.write(file_path + 'assets/js/app.js');
```

It's displaying the correct concatenated path to the file: `here/there/assets/js/app.js`.

**How can I incorporate variables in Gruntfile?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to use [Template strings](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) like this:

```js
all: [
    '<%= file_path %>/assets/js/app.js',
    '<%= file_path %>/admin/assets/js/admin.js',
]
```

Then configure your *Gruntfile.js* to this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    var today = new Date();
    var year  = today.getFullYear();

    grunt.initConfig({
        file_path: 'here/there', 
        //                    ^-- Note: there is no trailing forward slash.

        jshint: {
            all: [
                '<%= file_path %>/assets/js/app.js',
                '<%= file_path %>/admin/assets/js/admin.js',
            ]
        }

    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);

};
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Actually I tried this method once, though with a trailing slash in the variable. :(